# Making Retrofit request from DialogFragment

Tags: android, retrofit

I have implemented a login DialogFragment in my app (API 19).  I'm using Retrofit 1.7.1 for networking.  The implementation is below:

```
public class SignInDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {
    private EditText mUsernameEditText;
    private EditText mPasswordEditText;

    public static SignInDialogFragment newInstance() {
        return new SignInDialogFragment();
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                .setPositiveButton(R.string.action_sign_in, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        String username = mUsernameEditText.getText().toString();
                        APIFactory.getAPI().register(username, new Callback<RegistrationResponseModel>() {
                            @Override
                            public void success(RegistrationResponseModel registrationResponse, Response response) {
                                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Totally worked!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
                                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Something failed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        });
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton(R.string.action_cancel, null);

        View view = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.fragment_sign_in, null);
        builder.setView(view);

        mUsernameEditText = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.usernameEditText);

        return builder.create();
    }
}
```

As you might predict, this crashes upon success or failure when `getActivity()` hits a null reference.  **What is the best way to handle an asynchronous request such as this, including getting callbacks after the dialog has been dismissed?**

I thought of a few options; are any of them viable?

I could simply hold the dialog open if there is a request in progress.  I haven't implemented this because I'm not sure of the cleanest way to keep the dialog around (handling the Back button, etc).

I would really like to just cancel the Request if the dialog is closed, but I can't, because [there is not currently a way to cancel Retrofit requests](https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/319).

If there is an option that I'm not aware of, I'd like to hear about it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should move your action out of Dialog. Dialog is not Activity - once user did a choice, dialog should be dismissed and if there's any action to trigger it should be done as **response** to user action with dialog, but it should not be part of dialog. Therefore you should just react to user choice in your parent Fragment or Activity, not in Dialog.

Comment: Oh, I see. That makes so much more sense. I will probably call this logic from several other places, so should I put the response logic into a Fragment which launches this dialog?

Comment: Exactly. Dialog is just to get "feedback" from user, but where the main action goes is its parent object.

Comment: Awesome! I'll have to read more about headless Fragments then... I'm still not entirely sure how to handle someone leaving the Activity while there's an outstanding request. I think the headless Fragment should just unregister a `callbacks` member or something similar.

Comment: You can do thta in many ways - i.e. you can prevent leaving by overloading `onBackPressed()` but that's bad idea. You may want to show undismissable progress dialog (or whatever) locking whole UI unless you are done. Or you can just flag that user left you Fragment/Activity (i.e. in `onPause()` and when you async task is done, you check if you are still "detached" from the ui (for Fragment you can also use `isAdded()`) and act accordingly.